# python - join all threads after start_new_thread

Tags: python, multithreading

When using the thread library,
Is there a way to join all threads that were created by start_new_threads ?

for example:

```
try:    
    import thread 
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread #Py3K changed it.

for url in url_ip_hash.keys(): 
    thread.start_new_thread(check_url, (url,))
```

How can join all threads ?

Comment: How do You want to join them? You mean You want to wait until the thread terminates?

Comment: I want to wait until all the threads that were created by start_new_thread have finished their call back.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using `thread` instead of the recommended [Threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module? If not, you should rather use the `threading.Thread` objects which have a join method:

```
from threading import Thread


def check_url(url):
    # some code

threads = []
for url in url_ip_hash.keys():
    t = Thread(target=check_url, args=(url, ))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# join all threads
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Yes, i know this solution, but isnt there a way of doing it in thread lib ?

Comment: Since `thread` does not provide you with a `join` method, you have to implement it yourself. 

What you can do: you give each `check_url` method an additional parameter, a (locked!) lock. Each method gets its own lock, they are not sharing the same one. At the end of `check_url` you release the lock. This is the signal for the calling thread that the thread has finished.

Instead of the above `for t in threads: t.join()`, you try to acquire all locks which only runs through if all locks where released, (i.e. all `check_url` methods finished).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use _thread instead of threading.Thread, you can implement mutexes to know when your other threads are complete.

```
# make as many lock objects as you have threads ==> len(url_ip_hash.keys())
exitmutexes = [thread.allocate_lock() for _ in range of len(url_ip_hash.keys())]

def check_url(threadnum, url):
    "enter your code here"""
    exitmutexes[threadnum].acquire()

for url in url_ip_hash.keys(): 
    thread.start_new_thread(check_url, (url,))

# the mutex's lock method can be used to check its state. 
# continues in while loop until lock acquired for every exitmutex
for mutex in exitmutexes:
    while not mutex.locked(): pass
print('Program exited successfully.')
```

Another way is to make a global boolean list, assigning False to every item in the list, and switching them to True when your thread exits.

```
exitstatus = [False] * len(url_ip_hash.keys)

def check_url(threadnum, url):
    """ Enter your code here"""
    exitstatus[threadnum] = True

for url in url_ip_hash.keys(): 
    thread.start_new_thread(check_url, (threadnum, url))

while False in exitstatus: pass
print('Program exited successfully.')
```

As you can see, as mentioned earlier, it's much simpler to use the threading.Thread module and performing a .join. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Coding in `micropython` instead of plain `python` is one of the reasons one could need to use the `_thread` module instead of `threading`.

If that's your case, another alternative besides using `_thread` and implementing the join yourself, is to use `coroutines`, available in the `asyncio` module for python and `uasyncio` for micropython.

For example, if you simple want to wait for the function to execute, you can just call `asyncio.run(your_function())`.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support explanation. It helps to understand the resolution.